# How to use std::string as key of QHash?

Tags: c++, qt, qhash

I want to use a `std::string` as the key of a `QHash`:

```
QHash<std::string, QString> m_hash;
m_hash.insert("ABC", "DEF");
```

I implemented the required qHash:

```
inline qHash(const std::string& key, uint seed = 0)
{
  qHash(QByteArray::fromRawData(key.data(), key.length()), seed);
}
```

Everything compiles correctly using MSVC, but gcc generates the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to `qHash(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)`

How should I resolve this isse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Qt 6.1 and newer

Using `std::string` as a key is supported out of the box, as Qt now uses [`std::hash` as a fallback](https://www.kdab.com/qt-6-1-stdhash-support/) for `qHash`.

### Pre Qt 6.1

**Short answer**

Defining the `qHash` function inside the `std` namespace may resolve the compiler error, but **[adding a function to the `std` namespace is undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).** So, it is not allowed.

A workaround is to wrap `std::string` inside a helper class[[1]](https://www.kdab.com/how-to-declare-a-qhash-overload/):

```
class MyHashString : public std::string {};
QHash<MyHashString, QString> m_hash;
m_hash.insert("ABC", "DEF");

inline qHash(const MyHashString& key, uint seed = 0)
{
  qHash(QByteArray::fromRawData(key.data(), key.length()), seed);
}
```

**Long Answer**

As stated in this [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34912), one has to define the `qHash` function inside the namespace of `std::string`:

> This is documented in the C++ standard. It's called **Argument-Dependent Lookup**. It says that searching for an unqualified qHash(T) will find it in T's namespace.

So, the correct definition of the required `qHash` would be:

```
namespace std
{
  inline qHash(const std::string& key, uint seed = 0)
  {
    qHash(QByteArray::fromRawData(key.data(), key.length()), seed);
  }
}
```

It is also mentioned in the Qt docs:

> A QHash's key type has additional requirements other than being an assignable data type: it must provide operator==(), and there must also be a qHash() function **in the type's namespace** that returns a hash value for an argument of the key's type.

However, **[adding a function to the `std` namespace is undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).** So, one is stuck using a non-ideal workaround.

**Further reading**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl
- Interesting article about `qHash` overloading: https://www.kdab.com/how-to-declare-a-qhash-overload/